# Firebase Functions How To Handle Errors Properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-functions

## NOTE: this question is mainly about error handling, and if this is an ok approach, not about nesting promises, please read before closing

Since there are currently no error codes for services like firestore and firebase database, i'm using a system to know where the function failed and to handle error accordingly, simplified version below:

```
exports.doStuff = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return [promise doing stuff goes here].catch(error => { throw new Error('ERROR0') })
        .then(result => {
            return [promise doing stuff goes here, needs result of previous promise]
                .catch(error => { throw new Error('ERROR1') })
        })
        .then(result => {
            return [promise doing stuff goes here, needs result of previous promise]
                .catch(error => { throw new Error('ERROR2') })
        })
        .then(result => {
            //inform client function successful
            return {
                success: true
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error !== null) {
                switch (error.message) {
                    case 'ERROR0':
                        //do stuff
                        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'ERROR0');
                    case 'ERROR1':
                        //do stuff
                        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'ERROR1');
                    case 'ERROR2':
                        //do stuff
                        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'ERROR2');
                    default:
                        console.error('uncaught error: ', error);
                        throw error;
                }
            }
        });
});
```

the thing is, for each `.catch()` inside each returned promise, i'm getting the following warning: `warning  Avoid nesting promises`

so my question is, is there a better way to handle errors?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Since there are currently no error codes for services like firestore and firebase database..."  ... if one reads docs like this ... https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/Status ... we seem to see docs on error conditions.

Comment: @Kolban this sums it up https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/issues/45#issuecomment-479615071, pretty much no officially documented error messages, only exists for firebase auth on admin for now

Comment: As far as I can tell, your question **IS** actually about nesting promises, which eslint is telling you is a bad programming practice in that error message.  It's not about error codes.  See the duplicate for the preferred pattern.  If the duplicate doesn't answer your question, please ask again saying what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @DougStevenson, it's mainly about handling errors, and if there are any better  alternatives to handling errors. Also, the question linked doesn't even mention errors, and someone looking for an error handling solution might not find one in the linked answer (because that question isn't about error handling). The accepted answer here, by samthecodingman, I would say answers this question, because it provides a cleaner and better alternative to the error handling solution I came up with

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed and marked as a duplicate, the referenced answer has nothing to do with error handling. I have voted this question for re-opening @shmibbles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ultimately it's a style recommendation to prevent bizarre and hard to recognise errors. Most of the time a rewrite can eliminate the warning. As an example, you could rewrite your code as the following whilst retaining the same functionality.

```
exports.doStuff = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const result1 = await [promise doing stuff goes here]
      .catch(error => {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'ERROR0', { message: error.message } )
      });

    const result2 = await [promise based on result1 goes here]
      .catch(error => {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'ERROR1', { message: error.message } )
      });

    const result3 = await [promise based on result1/result2 goes here]
      .catch(error => {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'ERROR2', { message: error.message } )
      });

    return {
      success: true
    };
});
```

Lastly, rather than using `unknown` everywhere, you could use one of [several possible values for the first argument](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/d9fc8a6bb6e6a34e478bb6de98c64514e16ff1fa/src/providers/https.ts#L72-L110) whilst passing in whatever supporting information you need as the third argument (as shown above where I pass through the original error message).

Comment: that looks much cleaner, thanks for the answer