# Firebase auth sendEmailVerification not sending email // react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a sign up form for my react app using firebase auth.

The sign up function works great, it is just not sending a verification email. This is the code I am using:

```
  const registerUser = async (email, name, password) => {
    try {
      console.log("> Registering user")
      setLoading(true);
      const {
        user
      } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  
      console.log("> Updating profile")
      await updateProfile(user, {
        displayName: name,
      })
      .then(()=>{
        // send verification mail.
        sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser.email);
      auth.signOut();
      alert("Email sent");
    })
    .catch(alert); 
  
     window.location.pathname = `/subscriptions/${user.uid}`;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  
    setLoading(false)
  };
```

The alert("Email sent") works fine, and it has sent a verification email in the past. I changed it since then however and can't remember what I used to make it send the verification email.

Comment: The `sendEmailVerification` returns a promise to try using await and making the function async. The same goes for signout

Comment: Simple await or use then for `sendEmailVerification` and check your `spam` folder of gmail

Comment: Is it not already using then?    The auth.signOut() works currently and signs the user out, it's just not sending the email

Answer (score 2):

Avoid mixing traditional `.then().catch()` syntax with modern `async`/`await` syntax as it can lead to confusion.

In your code, you call both `sendEmailVerification()` and `auth.signOut()` without waiting for them to complete. This means that `alert("Email sent")` is called straight away, followed by `` window.location.pathname = `/subscriptions/${user.uid}` `` , which cancels those two operations.

```js
const registerUser = async (email, name, password) => {
  try {
    console.log("> Registering user")
    setLoading(true);
    const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  
    console.log("> Updating profile")
    await updateProfile(user, { displayName: name });

    await sendEmailVerification(user.email);

    await auth.signOut();

    alert("Email sent"); // avoid using alert() as it blocks the thread
  
    window.location.pathname = `/subscriptions/${user.uid}`;
  } catch (e) {
    // consider swapping below line to `setErrorMessage()` or similar
    // and display the message above your form
    alert('Failed to send email verification: ' + (e.message || e)); 
    console.error('Failed to send email verification: ', e);
  }
  
  setLoading(false)
};
```

If you want to use custom error messages after each step, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252909/3068190) to see how to use `catch()` to wrap the errors (however only use `new Error()` as `new functions.https.HttpsError()` is for server-side code).

Comment: I'm still not getting a verification email with this, it returns: 'TypeError: user.getIdToken is not a function'

Comment: @PeterBonnebaigt Where specifically is that being thrown? It would suggest that `user` isn't a proper `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sendEmailVerification()` expect a Firebase User, not an email. Thats mean that the correct way to use the function is `sendEmailVerification(user)`. The complete correct code is:

```
  const registerUser = async (email, name, password) => {
  try {
    console.log("> Registering user")
    setLoading(true);
    const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  
    console.log("> Updating profile")
    await updateProfile(user, { displayName: name });

    await sendEmailVerification(user); // pass user by param

    await auth.signOut();

    alert("Email sent"); // avoid using alert() as it blocks the thread
  
    window.location.pathname = `/subscriptions/${user.uid}`;
  } catch (e) {
    // consider swapping below line to `setErrorMessage()` or similar
    // and display the message above your form
    alert('Failed to send email verification: ' + (e.message || e)); 
    console.error('Failed to send email verification: ', e);
  }
  
  setLoading(false)
};
```